# default argument not being used

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I'm calling this function

```
void Board::insertWord(const string& s, const Clue& clue, 
    bool recordLetters=true) {
  ...
}
```

here

```
insertWord( newWord, curClue );
```

where `newWord` and `curClue` are a string and Clue, respectively. I can't figure out why the default value isn't being used for the third argument.

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -g board.cpp -o board.o
board.cpp: In member function ‘void Board::processUntilValid()’:
board.cpp:78:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘Board::insertWord(std::string&, const Clue&)’
         insertWord( newWord, curClue );
                                      ^
board.cpp:78:38: note: candidate is:
In file included from board.cpp:1:0:
board.h:42:10: note: void Board::insertWord(const string&, const Clue&, bool)
     void insertWord(const string& s, const Clue& c, bool recordLetters);
          ^
board.h:42:10: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
```

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It is impossible to determine what exactly is the problem, as you did not provide enough information. Please, provide a [mcve]. Especially I am interested in member function **declaration** (in header) and **definition** (in .cpp file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
void Board::insertWord(const string& s, const Clue& clue, 
                       bool recordLetters=true) { /* ... */ }
```

...is the definition of `Board::insertWord`. In c++, you do not put default argument when defining method but when declaring them, so your code should probably be:

```
class Board {
    // Declaration:
    void insertWord(const string& s, const Clue& clue, 
                    bool recordLetters = true);
};

// Definition:
void Board::insertWord(const string& s, const Clue& clue, 
                       bool recordLetters) { /* ... */ } // No default argument
```

Comment: exactly the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments belong in declaration (`.h`) and not in definition (`.cpp`).

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are the property of particular declaration of a function, not of the function itself. Each caller evaluates default arguments based on the declaration(s) of the function it's seen.

It is perfectly possible (if unwise) to have a setup like this:

**a.cpp**

```
void foo(int i = 42);

void a()
{
  foo();
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
void foo(int i = -42);

void b()
{
  foo();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

void a();
void b();

void foo(int i)
{
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  a();
  b();
}
```

This program will happily output `42` on one line and `-42` on the next, while being fully well-defined and conforming.

So, in your case, you must make sure that the caller has access to the declaration which defines the default argument. That declaration happens to be the function definition in your case. If that is hidden away in a .cpp file, you will probably want to move the default argument definition into a the function's declaration in a header file instead.